# Can we cast a vector containing superclass Objects into a vector containing subclass Objects?

Tags: java, vector

I have two vectors like this :

```
Vector<Animal> vAM = new Vector<Animal>();
Vector<Cat> vCat = new Vector<Cat>();
```

Is it possible to cast  the `vAM` vector into the `vCat` vector ? If not, then how should it be done ?

**Update :** The reason I mentioned this is I have a certain conversion here in my code which does not throw compile time exception , but it throws a run time exception . Hence I wanted to know whether there is any other way of doing this .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast you have in mind is just a compile-time artifact: you want the compiler to re-interpret an expression of the static type `Vector<Animal>` as an expression of type `Vector<Cat>`. That kind of re-interpretation violates static type safety, which is why it causes a compiler error.

If you really have the need for this, for example due to some mismatches in a 3rd-party API you are using, there is a way around the compiler check, but you'll still need to `@SuppressWarnings`:

```
vCat = (Vector<Cat>)(Vector)vAM;
```

Note that by doing this you lose the compiler's guarantee that `vAM` actually only contains cats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a direct cast. But i would not recommend to do so, as not every `animal` can be a `cat`. This would lead to `ClassCastExcpetions`.

I don't understand the need to do this cast, so I think its better to rethink the design of your program.